# The best way to group rows with same names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have that df:

```
gene  person  allele    allele2
A1      p1       G          C
A2      p1       A          C
A3      p1       A          T
A1      p2       G          C
A2      p2       T          T
A3      p2       G          C
A4      p2       A          T
A2      p1       G          C
A3      p1       C          C
...
```

As u can see, in table I can have same person few times (record form different laboratories). First p1 is different sample that second p1, and I need to pick only unique samples with best score (the highest number of rows), so it's that example it will be first p1 coz it's have 3 when another have 2.

And I have no idea how to extract that table to got something like this:

```
gene  person  allele    allele2
A1      p1       G          C
A2      p1       A          C
A3      p1       A          T
A1      p2       G          C
A2      p2       T          T
A3      p2       G          C
A4      p2       A          T
...
```

I thinking about indexing it by for loop. For example, add to index i if person == above person. If not, i+1. And then I will have a groups. But... whole df has 3mln row, so before I start I decide to describe here my problem. Maybe it's better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by compare [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then counts by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
g = df['person'].ne(df['person'].shift()).cumsum()
s = g.map(g.value_counts())

print (s)
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    2
8    2
Name: person, dtype: int64
```

And last compare by maxima value per `person` by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `Series` `s` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (s.groupby(df['person']).transform('max'))
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    3
8    3
Name: person, dtype: int64

df = df[s.groupby(df['person']).transform('max').eq(s)]
print (df)
  gene person allele allele2
0   A1     p1      G       C
1   A2     p1      A       C
2   A3     p1      A       T
3   A1     p2      G       C
4   A2     p2      T       T
5   A3     p2      G       C
6   A4     p2      A       T
```

EDIT: If need first group if same size, e.g. here group `p1` has same length 2 times:

```
#added last row for another data test
print (df)
  gene person allele allele2
0   A1     p1      G       C
1   A2     p1      A       C
2   A3     p1      A       T
3   A1     p2      G       C
4   A2     p2      T       T
5   A3     p2      G       C
6   A4     p2      A       T
7   A2     p1      G       C
8   A3     p1      C       C
9   A4     p1      C       C
```

---

```
g = df['person'].ne(df['person'].shift()).cumsum()
print (g)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: person, dtype: int32

#same size 3
s = g.map(g.value_counts())
print (s)
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: person, dtype: int64
```

---

```
#selected first max index in s
idx = s.groupby(df['person']).idxmax()
print (idx)
person
p1    0
p2    3
Name: person, dtype: int64

#seelcted groups g
print (g.loc[idx])
0    1
3    2
Name: person, dtype: int32
```

---

```
#selected only matched groups
print (g.isin(g.loc[idx]))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: person, dtype: bool

df = df[g.isin(g.loc[idx])]
print (df)
  gene person allele allele2
0   A1     p1      G       C
1   A2     p1      A       C
2   A3     p1      A       T
3   A1     p2      G       C
4   A2     p2      T       T
5   A3     p2      G       C
6   A4     p2      A       T
```

Comment: Wow! Great explanation, and it's work for me! thank u!